# What WiFi adapter can I use to monitor a WiFi network on OS X from a MBP?

Tags: macos, wifi, wireshark

I have MBP from early 2011 and Wireshark 1.8rc2 does not recognize it (under Lion).

What adaptors are compatible with it?

Alternatively, specify if there is a another software that I can use to monitor the traffic on a specific WiFi network (not encrypted).

Comment: Can you be more specific about what happens when you attempt a capture with Wireshark? AFAIK, Wireshark doesn't need to be "compatible" with an adapter. It only looks for network interfaces, not physical adapters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, the problem was that by default [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) did not monitor any interfaces but after going to the configuration they became visible and I was able to start monitoring them, even on promiscuous mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Debookee](http://www.iwaxx.com/debookee), a network traffic analyzer that also can intercept and analyze traffic of any device on your network: iPhone, iPad, TV, other computers ...